# React Cursor Tracking inside a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement cursor tracking in react such that when the cursor enters a particular component then a message should be displayed on bottom right of the cursor. The message should move along with the cursor.

I am implementing the functionality using **Render Props** as given in [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) page of React docs.

My component:

Message:

```
class Message extends Component {
    render() {
      const mouse = this.props.mouse;
      return (
        <span style={{ position: 'absolute', left: mouse.x, top: mouse.y }}>Hey I am tracking the cursor!</span>
      );  
    }
  }

  export default Message;
```

Mouse:

```
class Mouse extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.handleMouseMove = this.handleMouseMove.bind(this);
      this.state = { x: 0, y: 0 };
    }

    handleMouseMove(event) {
      this.setState({
        x: event.clientX,
        y: event.clientY,
      }); 
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div style={{ height: '100%' }} onMouseMove={this.handleMouseMove}>
          {this.props.render(this.state)}
        </div>
      );  
    }
  }

  export default Mouse;
```

Table: `<Table />`

```
import Table from 'path/to/table';
import Mouse from 'path/to/mouse';
import Message from 'path/to/message';

<Mouse render={mouse => (
  <Message mouse={mouse} />
)} />
<Table />
```

In this code, the tracking is enable only when the cursor enters the Message component. But if I change the code to something like below, I get the desired behaviour only when the cursor is inside the div the Mouse component is wrapped in, but the message is not rendered at bottom-right of the cursor.

Table: `<Table />`

```
import Table from 'path/to/table';
import Mouse from 'path/to/mouse';
import Message from 'path/to/message';

<div style={{ height: '700px', width: '700px'}}>
  <Mouse render={mouse => (
    <Message mouse={mouse} />
  )} />
</div>
<Table />
```

I am trying to make this functionality reusable through Render Props. My requirement is that whenever the cursor enters the Table component(in this case) or any other component (in general), the message that follows the cursor should pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the height of the message component which is 100% of the window when not wrapped and when wrapped it inherits the height of the parent component in this case which is the `div` component

Code without wrapping:

```
`<Mouse render={mouse => (
  <Message mouse={mouse} />
)} />`
```

Code after wrapping:

```
`<div style={{ height: "700px", width: "700px"}}>
     <Mouse render={mouse => (
         <Message mouse={mouse} />
      )} />
 </div>`
```

which causes the above behavior